# PHP: puzzled by variable expansion

Tags: php

I'm following the PHP Template example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617/whats-the-best-way-to-separate-php-code-and-html

My Template is:

```
class ViewTemplate {
private $args;
private $file;

public function __get($name) {
    return $this->args[$name];
}

public function __construct($file, $args = array()) {
    $this->file = $file;
    $this->args = $args;
}

public function render() {
    include $this->file;
}
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
    $event = "calendar";
    $view = new ViewTemplate('views/main.php', array(
        'topNav' => new ViewTemplate('views/topNav.php', array('login' => $login)),
        'leftPane' => new ViewTemplate('views/leftPane.php', array('login' => $login)),
        'mainContentNav' => new ViewTemplate('views/mainContentNav.php', array('login' => $login, 'event' => $event)),
        'mainContent'  => new ViewTemplate('views/mainContent/' + $event + '.php', array('login' => $login, 'event' => $event)),
        'footer'  => new ViewTemplate('views/footer.php', array('login' => $login))
    ));
```

I'm getting:

```
[12-Apr-2013 21:33:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(0): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Owner\PhpstormProjects\CRM\admin\classes\Lifestyle\ViewTemplate.php on line 23

[12-Apr-2013 21:33:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '0' for inclusion (include_path='C:\Users\Owner\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear;C:\Users\Owner\PhpstormProjects\CRM\admin\classes\Lifestyle\classes') in C:\Users\Owner\PhpstormProjects\CRM\admin\classes\Lifestyle\ViewTemplate.php on line 23
```

The problem seems to be the following bit, where I'm initializing the array:

```
'mainContent'  => new ViewTemplate('views/mainContent/' + $event + '.php', array('login' => $login, 'event' => $event)),
```

If I change that to:

```
'mainContent'  => new ViewTemplate('views/mainContent/calendar.php', array('login' => $login, 'event' => $event)),
```

Then it works, but it robs me of the dynamic use case I'd like.

What gives?

Comment: 'views/mainContent/' + $event + '.php' = 0.

Comment: PHP is not Javascript. http://php.net/language.operators.string - For the general guidance please see: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/2261774)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'mainContent'  => new ViewTemplate('views/mainContent/' + $event + '.php', array('login' => $login, 'event' => $event)),
```

PHP does not concatenate the same way JS does. In PHP the concatenation operator is `.`.

```
'mainContent'  => new ViewTemplate('views/mainContent/' . $event . '.php', array('login' => $login, 'event' => $event)),
```

would be right.

Comment: Ah, yes - hehe, a little lingual confusion there.  Thanks - one of those "if it was a snake it would have bit you".

Answer (score 1):

[PHP uses `.` for concatenation](https://www.php.net/language.operators.string). `+` is for addition only.

```
'views/mainContent/' . $event . '.php'
//                   ^        ^
```